# Oracle SQL to distribute Amount in Months between Dates

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, distribution

I have the following data from a table T1

A is Amount, N is Number of Weeks Between Start and End Date

```
StartDate   EndDate     Program Dept    Accnt   A       N
2-Sep-19    4-Jan-20    02DHM   103     40301   29400   17
2-Sep-19    4-Jan-20    30BHM   103     40304   3000    17
2-Sep-19    4-Jan-20    30BHM   103     40304   3000    17
2-Sep-19    4-Jan-20    32BIT   102     40204   3000    17
```

My desired output is below:

```
StartDate End Date  Program Dept    Accnt   A       N           1    2  3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
2-Sep-19  4-Jan-20  02DHM   103     40301   29400   17          A/N  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   A/N A/N A/N A/N
2-Sep-19  4-Jan-20  30BHM   103     40304   3000    17          A/N  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   A/N A/N A/N A/N
2-Sep-19  4-Jan-20  30BHM   103     40304   3000    17          A/N  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   A/N A/N A/N A/N
2-Sep-19  4-Jan-20  32BIT   102     40204   3000    17          A/N  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   A/N A/N A/N A/N
```

The value Amount/Num of Weeks is mentioned for the month between Start and End Date
where Column Num 1 to 12 Represents the number of months.

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  Weeks?  Months?  Numbers?  Strings?  Do you just want `'A/N'` and `0` in the 12 columns?

Comment: yes, where A is the Amount and N is the number of Weeks; only for months which falls between Start Date and End Date, else it should be 0

Comment: So, columns 1 through 12 stand for month #1 (January) through #12 (December), and your example shows `A/N` for month 1, 9, 10, 11, 12, right?  Still not clear whether you want a static `A/N` in those columns in the detail lines, or, for example, `24900/17` for the first row.

Comment: Yes @MarkStewart, the example is correct.